# HTML table column width for different rows

Tags: html

I have a form which includes only text and text inputs. It looks like:[image]

How to change column width for each rows of the table?

Comment: You can change the column width in the corresponding css for the row. Can you be more specific with some example code?

Comment: What if I have several dozens of rows?

Answer (score 1):

It is not a table.

Tables are for tabular data.

Format the form using CSS.

Comment: I want to use tables for templating.

Comment: @lolli - Only use tables for tabular data. Otherwise use CSS to do the formating. It will work as a template.